# Cut points falling in a polygon out of the point cloud

Tags: r, lidr

Using lidR 3.1.3, is it possible to classify points inside polygons shapefile for a `LASCatalog`, something like the previous [`lasclassify()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/1.6.1/topics/lasclassify) function. I'm looking for a equivalent of this [PDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328983/change-lidar-classification-of-points-inside-polygons) method.

```r
ctg <- lidR::readLAScatalog(path_to_folder)
shapefile = rgdal::readOGR(shapefile_file)
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(path_to_folder, "/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_classified")

# Need to classify here
output<- classify_within_polygons(ctg, shapefile)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `clip_roi()` function?

Comment: The opposite : get only points outside the geometry

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify your wish an try to provide a base of code we can use or at least an picture of what you want. Otherwise your question is likely to get closed for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a loaded point-cloud (`LAS`) you can use `merge_spatial()`. Lets load some data first:

```r
library(lidR)
library(sf)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
shp <- system.file("extdata", "lake_polygons_UTM17.shp", package = "lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
poly <- st_read(shp, quiet = TRUE)
plot(las@header)
plot(poly, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

We can now use `merge_spatial()` to know if points are in or out the polygon(s). Then we can use this information to clip or classify.

```r
las <- merge_spatial(las, poly, "inpoly")
las$Classification[las$inpoly == TRUE] <- LASWATER
las$Classification[las$inpoly == FALSE & las$Classification != LASGROUND] <- LASLOWVEGETATION
plot(las, color = "Classification")

veg = filter_poi(las, inpoly == FALSE)
plot(veg)
```

However it is not possible (yet) to directly classify the point-cloud from a `LAScatalog`. You must build your own tools based on this answer and `catalog_apply()`

Comment: I didn't know `merge_spatial()`, it works perfectly. Thanks for the clear answer and examples.